# My program is being reported as a high-level security threat by AVG?

Tags: xna-4.0, antivirus, virus

I recently started distributing my XNA 4.0 game to people. On computers with AVG installed, it detected this game as a false positive virus with a high security threat.

I have no idea of what is going on. All I know is that when it happened, there was an infinite loop issue. Could this be detected by AVG as a criteria for virus detection?

How can I report a false positive to AVG? I found this website http://www.geekstogo.com/forum/topic/273320-where-to-submit-false-positives-to-antivirus-and-security-vendors/

But under AVG, it only shows how to submit false positive websites.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can get more information in order to handle the false positive with AVG at the below link. Make sure to check out section IV.

http://www.avg.com/us-en/whitelist

As far as the false positive goes, I am not intimately familiar with virus scanners, but there are probably tons of reasons your software could have triggered a false positive. Perhaps the code (coincidentally) matches some part of a virus signature, or perhaps heuristic matching (which looks for certain behavioral patterns in software)  flagged it as suspicious (are you deleting files? doing funky things with memory? using polymorphic code?, etc). I doubt an infinite loop in itself could have lead to the issue though.